# I am trying to make a cosine law calculator in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program that takes side "a" and side "b" and angle "C". Then it will output side "c".

I am getting an int error and I don't know whats wrong
Here is my code:

```
import math
def triangle():
    a=input("Enter side a:")
    b=input("Enter side b:")
    angle=input("What is the angle:")
    side=(a**2)+(b**2)
    rest=(2*(a*b))(math.cos(angle))
    done=side-rest
    end=math.sqrt(done)
    print end
triangle()
```

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Unrelated to your error, but do you input the angle in degrees, or radians?  If degrees, you should convert to radians before passing it to math.cos().

Comment: Thanks Jim Lewis that fixed the calculation error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
rest=(2*(a*b))(math.cos(angle))
```

You are missing a `*` operator:

```
rest=(2*(a*b))*(math.cos(angle))
```

You've also got some excessive use of parenthesis:

```
rest = 2 * a * b * math.cos(angle)
```

The cause of the problem is that python thought you were trying to invoke the result of the expression `(2*(a*b))`. However that is an `int`, and it is not a callable object.

Answer (score 4):

It might because you missed a "*" in:

```
rest=(2*(a*b))(math.cos(angle))
```

it should be:

```
rest=(2*(a*b)) * (math.cos(angle))
```

Comment: I wanted to note that an opening parenthesis following any object declaration will try to call that object. Python thought you were saying something like `2*(a*b).__call__(math.cos(angle))`